# Вертикальное выравнивание bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Как выровнять текст по середине

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-4">
          Boostfolia
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 text-right">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Menu
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">menu 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">menu 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">menu 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner align-middle">
    <div class="carousel-item active text-center bg-grey">
      <!-- <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> -->
      <div>WE THINK CREATIVE BE CREATIVE</div>
      <div>LIKE TO DO CREATIVE WORKS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center bg-grey">
      <!-- <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> -->
      <div>WE THINK CREATIVE BE CREATIVE</div>
      <div>LIKE TO DO CREATIVE WORKS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center bg-grey">
      <!-- <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> -->
      <div>WE THINK CREATIVE BE CREATIVE</div>
      <div>LIKE TO DO CREATIVE WORKS</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">ABOUT US</div>
    <div class="line">line</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="col">CREATIVE DESIGN</div>
      <div class="col">CREATIVE PORTFOLIO</div>
      <div class="col">INFINITE UPDATES</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто используй flex...

```
.box {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: так не работает потому что слайдер ломается

Answer (score 0):

Для блоков d-flex или row используйте 
align-items-center